# How can I modify the title of a site using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, document, title

When viewing a torrent page, the title of the tab is:

> Bitsoup.org The Best site for your Torrent appetite :: Details for
>   torrent "ABC"

where "ABC" is the name of the torrent file.

Unfortunately, when I have 3+ tabs open, I can not see what the name of the torrent file is.

I am attempting to create a Greasemonkey script to truncate, or split, the title, so that it only displays the torrent-name, and not the beginning part.

I am aware that you can modify the title associated with a page by using `document.title = ...`

but I am unsure of what to assign it to.

Comment: `document.title = document.title.substr(76);` ? If it's off by one or two just modify the number, this just fetches everything after the specified character index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a regular expression, perhaps:

```
document.title = document.title.match(/"([^"]+)"/)[1]
```

This regex uses grouping to matches the first thing that is between quotes, and assigns it to the `title` (without the quotes).

Answer (score 3):

Using a substr method is by far the simplest if you know that the beginning of the title will always be identical. For example, with the title you gave:

```
document.title = document.title.substr(76);
```

If it is not a static title, then RegEx would be the next most logical route. To match the last set of quotes and ignore potential whitespace:

```
document.title = document.title.match(/"([^"]+)"\s*$/)[1];
```

Comment: This is a more complete answer. :)